# Points bar is not getting loaded in stackoverflow

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

When I hover the arrow near my name in stackoverflow, used to open the points bar(*not the correct word to refer*).  But now it is not getting loaded(around 30 mins).

[image]

I guess, since they are working on SQL server issues.  Just to let you know.

**EDIT:**
I got back my "reputation summary popup" But there are some alignment issues within it. See this screenshot

[image]

Comment: Actually I thought you meant you see points in the bar, lol!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd my mistake, may I know the right terms for the hover box?

Comment: No official name, best I can think of is "reputation summary popup".

Comment: I got back my "reputation summary popup" But there are some alignment issues within it.  Take a look at this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HvpyB.png)

Comment: Well, this is worth adding to the original report that your question was closed as duplicate of. Post it there as comment and ask the OP to embed into his post.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Sorry I misunderstood,  just now posted as a comment on `Sklivvz` answer.

Comment: Marking as status-completed of the original bug report here.

Comment: @Oded My second edit in this my question is not fixed.  The badge names are still missing.

Comment: It should never have been an edit - not for something like that. In particular after it was closed as a duplicate of another question (with the same original issue). It should have been a new question.

Comment: Regardless - this second issue was [also reported separately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208886/badge-names-have-disappeared-from-activity-dropdown) and is also fixed (pending a build).

Comment: @Oded Sorry never happen again, I didn't see this [updates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/208875/5).  Since people we're working SQL Server issue, I thought it better to edit the previous than adding new question.  I can feel that SO people had a hard day, great work. Thank you.