# Badge names have disappeared from activity dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, activity-dropdown

[image: Nice badges]

Well, I'm honoured, obviously!
I've always wanted those ones...

<sub>(Firefox 25.0.1 on Windows XP SP3)</sub>

Comment: Related: [profile-hover-quick-view-thingy-isnt-loading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208865/)

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 31 on Mac OS X.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: Read the answer below; it hasn't been rolled out yet.

Comment: Reproduced on FF

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next build out.

Note: builds are reduced today due to some other circumstances. It might be a while.

Comment: Can you please not set a bug to status-completed until it's deployed? It's great that you checked it in and everything, and thank you for that, but setting a bug to fixed before it's deployed is misleading to users.

Comment: A `status-scheduled` may be more appropriate.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO We don't have a [meta-tag:status-scheduled] state amd [meta-tag:status-planned] is for stuff we wish to do in the future, but not right now.

Comment: @Sklivvz perhaps you want to `status-planned` [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)?

Comment: Yep, it's fixed.

Comment: @Sklivvz: I agree with Aaron. It may have been fixed for you but, at the time, it was not fixed for us!