# "logout" link in multi-collider drop-down in mobile has moved to a precarious position

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, stack-exchange-button

Recently (perhaps due to the changes that caused [this and other bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208886/badge-names-have-disappeared-from-activity-dropdown)), the logout link in the drop-down on mobile (I use iPhone iOS 7.0 and Chrome, but it also happens in Safari) has moved to a position which makes it much more likely to click inadvertently when I'm actually trying to click on my profile link.

Here is the link as it currently appears in [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

And here is how it looks on Stack Overflow:

[image]

It doesn't look like we're out of horizontal real estate there, so I'm not quite sure why we're bumping down to the next line at all.

Comment: Maybe they are trying to tell us something, Aaron.

Comment: @Andrew well I already know I'm a heathen for using Apple products. Is this kind of thing just meant to rub it in?

Answer (score 1):

This does not happen with the new top bar - marking as complete.